# Run a function at the start of every round 5 minute interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I want to run a function every 5 minutes, it must be at a "round" intervals, for example :

```
12:05:00, 12:10:00, 12:15:00...
```

It cannot be like this:

```
12:06:00, 12:11:00, 12:16:00...
```

Or like this:

```
12:05:14, 12:10:14, 12:15:14...
```

What is the most accurate way to do this in python?

Comment: Check the time every second with a `while` loop and `if` it is one of those kinds of times, execute the function... But: The fact that you mention Scheduled Tasks, make me think you need `cron` on linux or window's task scheduler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `threading.Timer`. You have to do some math to calculate the next run time. `datetime` has a handy `replace` method for that.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep
import random

def schedule_next_run():
    sleep_time = get_sleep_time()
    t = Timer(sleep_time, do_work)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    print(f'sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds')

def get_sleep_time():
    now = datetime.now()
    last_run_time = now.replace(minute=now.minute // 5 * 5, second=0, microsecond=0)
    next_run_time = last_run_time + timedelta(minutes=5)
    return (next_run_time - now).total_seconds()

def do_work():
    now = datetime.now()
    print('Doing some work at', now)
    sleep(random.uniform(0, 29))
    print('Work complete. Scheduling next run.')
    schedule_next_run()

print('Starting work schedule')
schedule_next_run()
input('Doing work every 5 minutes. Press enter to exit:\n')
```

On my system, the function fires within a half millisecond of the target time

Note that the time calculation rounds down and then adds a `timedelta` to carefully wrap around the end of each hour. You would want to ponder how this will behave around daylight savings changes.

**Suggestion**: move all this logic to a class to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime and condition.

```
import datetime

while True:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    if current_time.second % 5 == 0 and current_time.minute % 1 == 0 and current_time.microsecond == 0:

        print(current_time)
```

[image]

hope this helps.

Comment: Very simple solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime, time

def some_function():

ran_once = True

while True:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    if  current_time.minute % 5 == 0 and current_time.second % 60 == 0 and not ran_once:
        print(current_time) # DO YOUR WORK HERE
        ran_once = True

    elif current_time.minute % 5 == 0 or current_time.second % 60 != 0:

        if current_time.second % 60 == 0:
            print("Time to wait:", 5 - (current_time.minute % 5), "minutes and 0 seconds")
        else:
            print("Time to wait:", 4 - (current_time.minute % 5), "minutes and ", end="")
            print(60 - (current_time.second % 60), "seconds")

        time.sleep( (4 -(current_time.minute % 5))*60 + 60 -(current_time.second % 60))

        ran_once = False
```

The above code runs at intervals of 5 minutes. Initially, the main thread sleeps for the number of seconds required to reach the perfect timestamp. For example, if the program is started at 7:28:30 then it is going to sleep for 90 seconds and then start at 7:30:00. From then on it will wait for 5 minutes before it runs the required functionality again.

Also, I think the performance of firing up at the exact second really varies on how your system handles the threads.